# File Transfer with Sockets on Python

Tags: python, sockets

Trying to build a simple file transfer with sockets on Python. I got stuck and it seems that I can't send any part of the file.

Following some advice, I've tried to send the last line of the file, so I can know when to finish the connection.

But it happens that once I send the first package, the client never gets the rest.

Here you will see my code (Server side):

```
import os
import socket
PORT = 8080
HOST = 'localhost'
socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.bind((HOST,PORT))
socket.listen(10)
conn, addr = socket.accept()
print '\033[46m\033[34m\033[1mBienvenido al File Sender v.0.02 hecho en Python. Este         programa permite enviar archivos a traves de tu maquina\033[0m'
ANSI_RED = '\033[31m'
ANSI_BLUE = '\033[34m'
ESCAPEANSI = '\033[0m'
def seleccion_path():
PATH = raw_input('\033[34m\033[1mSelect the Path (./ by default)').strip('n')
if PATH == '':
    PATH = os.getcwd()   
print PATH, ESCAPEANSI
acepta_path = raw_input('\033[34m\033[1mSi o No (S/N)').lower().strip(' ')
if acepta_path == 's' or acepta_path == 'si':
    return PATH
else:
    seleccion_path()
def filesDir(path):
files = os.listdir(PATH)
for fl in files:
    i = int(files.index(fl))+1
    print ANSI_RED + str(i)+ ')' + fl
return files

PATH = seleccion_path()
print 'el PATH seleccionado es:', PATH + '\n'
filesDir(PATH)
fileSelected = int(raw_input(ANSI_BLUE + 'Select a file with the number').strip(' ').lower()) 
print PATH + filesDir(PATH)[fileSelected-1]
fileToSend = open(PATH + filesDir(PATH)[fileSelected-1], 'rb')
qLines = len(open(PATH + filesDir(PATH)[fileSelected-1], 'rb').readlines())

finalLine = cpfileToSend.readlines()[qLines-1]
conn.send(finalLine)
while True:
    data = conn.sendall(fileToSend.readline())
    conf = conn.recv(1024)
    print conf
    if conf == 'OK':
        conn.close()
        fileToSend.close()
         break
print '\033[43m File sent'
#Finaliza el programa y deja los codigos ANSI cerrados
print ESCAPEANSI
exit()
```

Here is the Client:

```
import os
import socket
PORT = 8080
HOST = 'localhost'

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.connect((HOST, PORT))
fname = open('./fileSent.pdf', 'w+')

finalLine = socket.recv(1024)
print finalLine
while True:
    strng = socket.recv(2048)
    print 'aaaaa',strng
    fname.write(strng)
    if finalLine in strng:
        fname.write(strng)
        socket.send('OK')
        socket.close()
fname.close()
print 'Data received correctly' 
exit()
```

Comment: why are you sending last line at the beginning of transfer? I think it would be better to send the length of your file instead.

Comment: What's wrong with using HTTP?

Comment: Nothing wrong! I was exploring. I've figured out how to do it. I'll post it right away! Thank you everybody for the concern and your help.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I was able to do it. The problem was with the socket.recv(). I was asking for the application to execute several lines, but nothing arrived from the server.The client never executed the lines below that one, because it was expecting data to keep on running the next lines.
I rearranged the code to deal with this, and it's working great.
Definitely love Python :)

Server side:

```
import os
import socket
PORT = 8080
HOST = 'localhost'
socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.bind((HOST,PORT))
socket.listen(1)
conn, addr = socket.accept()
print '\033[46m\033[34m\033[1mBienvenido al File Sender v.0.02 hecho en Python. Este programa permite enviar archivos a traves de tu maquina\033[0m'
ANSI_RED = '\033[31m'
ANSI_BLUE = '\033[34m'
ESCAPEANSI = '\033[0m'
def seleccion_path():
PATH = raw_input('\033[34m\033[1mSelect the Path (./ by default)').strip('n')
if PATH == '':
    PATH = os.getcwd()   
print PATH, ESCAPEANSI
acepta_path = raw_input('\033[34m\033[1mSi o No (S/N)').lower().strip(' ')
if acepta_path == 's' or acepta_path == 'si':
    return PATH
else:
    seleccion_path()
def filesDir(path):
files = os.listdir(PATH)
for fl in files:
    i = int(files.index(fl))+1
    print ANSI_RED + str(i)+ ')' + fl
return files

PATH = seleccion_path()
print 'el PATH seleccionado es:', PATH + '\n'
filesDir(PATH)
fileSelected = int(raw_input(ANSI_BLUE + 'Select a file with the number').strip(' ').lower()) 
print PATH + filesDir(PATH)[fileSelected-1]

filepath = PATH + filesDir(PATH)[fileSelected-1]
#envia nombre del file
conn.send(filepath)
qLines = len(open(PATH + filesDir(PATH)[fileSelected-1], 'rb').readlines())
fileToSend = open(filepath, 'rb')
while True:
data = fileToSend.readline()
if data:
    conn.send(data)
else:
    break
fileToSend.close()
conn.sendall('')
conn.close()

print '\033[43m File sent'  
#Finaliza el programa y deja los codigos ANSI cerrados
print ESCAPEANSI
exit()
```

Client side:

```
import os
import socket
PORT = 8080
HOST = 'localhost'

nombrearchivo = raw_input('define a name with its extension').strip(' ')
socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.connect((HOST, PORT))
filename = socket.recv(1024)

fname = open('./'+nombrearchivo, 'wb')

while True:
strng = socket.recv(1024)
if strng:
    print strng
    fname.write(strng)
else:
    fname.close()
    break
socket.close()
print 'Data received correctly' 
exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem stems from the fact that you open the file, read all the lines (with `readlines`) and then try to read the file again without closing it.

I share @T_12's concern about why you want to send the last line of the file first. But assuming that you have a need to do so, here is the fix that you need:

Replace this part of your severside code (since I don't see where you've defined `cpfileToSend`, I assume that it was meant to be `fileToSend`)

```
fileToSend = open(PATH + filesDir(PATH)[fileSelected-1], 'rb')
qLines = len(open(PATH + filesDir(PATH)[fileSelected-1], 'rb').readlines())

finalLine = cpfileToSend.readlines()[qLines-1]
conn.send(finalLine)
while True:
    data = conn.sendall(fileToSend.readline())
    conf = conn.recv(1024)
    print conf
    if conf == 'OK':
        conn.close()
        fileToSend.close()
         break
```

with this

```
filepath = PATH + filesDir(PATH)[fileSelected-1]
fileToSend = open(filepath, 'rb')
qLines = len(open(PATH + filesDir(PATH)[fileSelected-1], 'rb').readlines())

finalLine = fileToSend.readlines()[qLines-1]
conn.send(finalLine)
fileToSend.close()
fileToSend = open(filepath, 'rb')
while True:
    data = conn.sendall(fileToSend.readline())
    conf = conn.recv(1024)
    print conf
    if conf == 'OK':
        conn.close()
        fileToSend.close()
         break
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have no specific concern on sending the last line. I've seen that is necessary to specify when is the file ending, so it sends a signal that end the loops and the connection. I've copied what you've sent me , but I can't transfer the whole file. Printing the chunks that are coming to the client, I only see the first line and nothing else.

Comment: On the server side, print what you want to send before you send it, to see if the file handle hasn't gone stale. If that works as expected, then try flushing the socket after every write, just in case it's overflowing